# Two legend issues with d3 chart

Tags: json, d3.js

I have a chart built in d3 to display who is speaking and where during the course of a play.  The characters are represented by color bars, and I'd like to provide a legend.  However, my legend code displays in a single column vertically and displays the same character name multiple times.  I know the latter is because it's parsing each record in the json, but I'm not sure how to have it mention each character only once other than providing a list of characters in the same way I provide a list of locations in my code.  Is there a way I can do this from the json instead?

Also, how would I organize the legend in a grid so as to utilize the white space in the upper left portion of the chart? I created a fiddle with the code I currently have at https://jsfiddle.net/3f7xrgeb/, and have also pasted it below.  My working copy (in case the fiddle does not display) is at http://www.matthewedavis.net/Magdalene_playtext/test_bars.html.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
    var margin = {top: 50, right: 150, bottom: 50, left: 150},
        w = 2500 - margin.left - margin.right,
        h = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    d3.json("http://www.matthewedavis.net/Magdalene_playtext/test_chart.json", function(json) {

        var data = json.items;

        var test = function(d) { return d.starting_line + d.duration; };

        var stage_directions = ([44, 49, 114, 140, 209, 217, 249, 257, 265, 277, 305, 334, 358, 381, 398, 409, 440, 470, 491, 547, 555, 564, 572, 587, 614, 630, 640, 691, 704, 725, 743, 775, 793, 818, 823, 841, 845, 868, 872, 888, 902, 910, 920, 925, 963, 993, 1005, 1023, 1031, 1047, 1061, 1096, 1125, 1133, 1143, 1178, 1210, 1228, 1281, 1293, 1336, 1349, 1376, 1395, 1439, 1446, 1454, 1538, 1554, 1562, 1578, 1598, 1610, 1618, 1642, 1646, 1716, 1725, 1743, 1781, 1791, 1797, 1843, 1863, 1887, 1915, 1923, 1939 ,1972, 1989, 2019, 2031, 2039, 2045, 2073, 2085, 2101, 2123])

        var x = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, 2200])
        .range([0, w]);

        var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .domain(["The priest's cell","The Cloud","Wilderness","The mountain","The Lodge","Marseilles","The Ship","Heaven","Heathen Temple","Sepulchre","The Stations","Palace of the King of Marseilles","Lazarus' tomb","Simon the Leper's House","Arbor","Jherusalem","Tavern","Hellmouth","The Place","Stage Above Hell","King of Flesh's location","King of the World's location","Pilate's location","Herod's location","Magdalene Castle","Tiberius' Palace"])
        .rangeBands([0, h]);

        var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left");

        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom");

        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", w + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", h + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        svg.append("text") 
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + (w / 2) + " ," + (h + margin.bottom - 5) +")")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text("Line Number");

        var t;
        for (t in stage_directions){
        svg.append("rect")
        .attr("class", "overlay")
        .attr("x",stage_directions[t])
        .attr("width", 1)
        .attr("height", h)
        .style ("fill", "black")
        .style ("opacity", 0.3);
    }

        svg.append("rect")
        .attr("class", "overlay")
        .attr("x",1)
        .attr("width", 1133)
        .attr("height", h)
        .style ("fill", "red")
        .style ("opacity", 0.1);

        svg.append("rect")
        .attr("class", "overlay")
        .attr("x",1133)
        .attr("width", 857)
        .attr("height", h)
        .style ("fill", "yellow")
        .style ("opacity", 0.1);

        svg.append("rect")
        .attr("class", "overlay")
        .attr("x",1990)
        .attr("width", 134)
        .attr("height", h)
        .style ("fill", "green")
        .style ("opacity", 0.1);

        svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + h + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

        svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis)

        var bars = svg.selectAll(".bar")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("class", function(d, i) {return "bar " + d.character;})
        .attr("x", function(d, i) {return d.starting_line;})
        .attr("y", function(d, i) {return y(d.location);})
        .attr("width", function(d, i) {return d.duration;})
        .attr("height", 15)
        .style("fill", function(d,i) {return "#" + d.color;});


        var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
        .data(data)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "legend")
        .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

        legend.append("rect")
        .attr("x", 10)
        .attr("width", 10)
        .attr("height", 10)
        .style("fill", function(d,i) {return "#" + d.color;});

        legend.append("text")
        .attr("x", 22)
        .attr("y", 5)
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .text(function(d) { return d.character; });

        svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "legend")
        .call(legend)
    });
```

Comment: Unfortunately css won't work for this because I need to reuse the code with other data sets and can't write custom css every time.  I have found a solution, though:

Eventually this will be used for other sets of data, so generating custom css for each set could be a problem.  I found a solution, though, which I will post as another comment.

Comment: `   var listCharacters = d3.set(data.map(function(d){ return d.character})).values();

      listColors = [];

      for(l in listCharacters){
        for (var key in data){
          if (listCharacters[l] === data[key].character) {
            if (listColors.indexOf(data[key].color) > -1)
            {}
            else
              {
                listColors.push(data[key].color)
              }
          }
          else {}
       }
      }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

First, create an array with the list of characters, avoiding duplicates:

```
var listCharacters = d3.set(data.map(function(d){ return d.character})).values();
```

Then, use it as the data for your legend:

```
var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
.data(listCharacters)
.enter()
//the test of the code...
```

And change the `text`:

```
.text(function(d,i){ return listCharacters[i]});
```

For the colours, do the same:

```
var listColors = d3.set(data.map(function(d){ return d.colour})).values(); //check the spelling in your object
```

And color the rectangles according to the index:

```
.attr("fill", function(d,i){ return listColors[i]});
```

To understand what it does, please read this:
https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays

Comment: That results in a sequence of black boxes, with no text or color information, and I'm not sure if it's correctly mapping the sequence or not.  Would I also need to change the "rect" and "text" sections below to reflect this, or include my color information in the set of values in the return statement for d3.set?

Comment: I added that to my answer, please have a look.

Comment: That's weird.  The text labels work great but the colors aren't mapping correctly.  It looks like d3.set doesn't lay out the values arbitrarily in the same way each time it runs.  i'll have to see if there's a way to handle the colors differently -- maybe check the json based on the values in the character list.

Comment: I told you the first time, in you other question: don't set the colors using JSON. Simply set the class of each rectangle (both the chart and the legend) with the name of the character, and set the color using CSS, according to the class.